# How to skip lines and write to certain cells in a spreadsheet program using Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, file-writing

I need to pull data from a database using SQL and then write that data to an Excel spreadsheet using Python. I have to skip the first two rows and the print to certain cells including two that include certain dates. Below these cells will be the headers and then the data itself.

This is what it should look like in the spreadsheet program:

> |_____________|_____________|_________|_____________|
>
> |_____________|_____________|_________|_____________|
>
> | DAILY________| PRODUCT___| BUILD:___|_____________|
>
> | Between______| 01-Mar-2017__| and______| 31-Mar-2017__|

How do I skip those first 2 lines in the spreadsheet and how do I print to certain cells with a break to go to the next row?

This is what I have so far:

```
    wb2 = RV.open_excel()
    RV.add_sheet_excel(['PRODUCT_CODE','PACKLIST_ID','PART_ID',
                              'QTY','UNIT_PRICE','VALUE'], wb2, 'Sheet 1')


    rep_view.multiLineOutput2(curs,sSQL=SQL20,justLen=[20,15,20,5,9,10],
    colFormat = ['S','S','S','Q','d','d'], V_TotalFormat=['N','N','N','N','N','N'],
    extraColFormular=[], TotalZeroRowSkip=False, nullChar='0',
    hideColumn = ['N','N','N','N','N','N'], wb = wb2, sheetTitle = 'Sheet1')
    rep_view.save_excel(wb2, FILE2)
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Try to break it into smaller tasks. Do you know how to query the DB? Do you need / know how to write a csv file? an xlsx file? Also show your own effort.

Comment: @DeepSpace my question is exactly what I asked at the end. I don't need help writing to a CSV file or pulling data. I only need help with skipping rows and writing to certain cells (hardcoding what is in those cells I showed in the diagram).